# Sevlte 404 localhost error after refreshing dynamic route

Tags: svelte

I have a svelte app with svelte-navigator running on localhost, the routing works fine, except when I refresh a page, then I get a 404 Error, page not found.

```
<script>
  import { Router, Route } from "svelte-navigator";

</script>

<Router>

 <Route path="/">
   <Login />
 </Route>

 <Route path="/myhome">
   <MyHome />
 </Route>

</Router>
```

Answer (score 1):

That package appears to do client-side SPA routing, so your server, whatever that is, has to return the same page for whatever path is requested or you need to configure a 404 fallback page if it allows for that.

Comment: So it is not possible with this setup to do a refresh?

Comment: It should be, if the server returns the same page that is returned for the root (`/`). It's not about the component. Though you can use different routers that do not use the path at all, e.g. [`svelte-spa-router`](https://github.com/ItalyPaleAle/svelte-spa-router/), which uses the fragment (`#`).